Which variable is best suited for edge weights when computing graph algorithms instead of relative risks?
I am currently trying to develop graph data. Which variable is best suited for edge weights when computing graph algorithms?

Relative risk
Relative Risk: Many networks in my field use relative risks for edge weights. However, I want to compute algorithms such as shortest path finding. Relative risk is the ratio of this risk between two groups, so it may not be suitable to use as a score in these algorithms.

Probabilities
I think using probabilities would make it easier to compute algorithms. However, in my data, every node has probabilities associated with every other node. Many of these are insignificant, random incidents. That's why other researches used relative risks.


I've considered other variables such as absolute risk, attributable risk, etc. However, I couldn't decide which one would be suitable as a graph edge weight. Could you recommend some good variables?
